# Manipulating localStorage?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a javascript object similar to this:

```
var Upgrades = {
     upgrade1: {
          name: 'First Upgrade',
          info: 'First Upgrades info',
          level: 1,
          cost: 10,
     },
     upgrade2: {
          name: 'Second Upgrade',
          info: 'Second Upgrades info',
          level: 1,
          cost:  200,
     },
     upgrade3: {
          name: 'Second Upgrade',
          info: 'Second Upgrades info',
          level: 1,
          cost: 4000,
     },
};
```

Now, saving this into the localStorage would be a breeze.

```
localStorage.setItem('Upgrades', JSON.stringify(Upgrades));
```

Problem is I need the level's value saved only, for each upgrade. Saving an entire object brings some problems, some of them being:

-If i'd want to change the name / info in my objects, I'd have to delete my saved localstorage file since it overwrites the Upgrades object with an old, stored name / info in there every time player enters the game.

-Adding more stuff (upgrades) to the object also crashes the game for some reason, and I'm not quite sure why. Whenever I add more upgrades to the object, I have to remove saved file again in order to play, from start

(or change saved file if it's different from the current object so it applies the save properly, but I don't know how to do that. It also sounds kind of nasty, because I guess you'd have to check if game-version from the object is the same, and if it isn't edit it so it corresponds to the current versions object.

Everything in the object is being calculated based by level (except strings). That's why I only need level saved.

How would I manipulate the localstorage?
I suppose loop through all the upgrades, and save each level value into different localStorage. So a localStorage for upgrade1, 2 and 3, containing only 'level: x'. And then same loop, when the player starts the game to apply saved level.
But can I do this with only 1 localStorage file? Would it be bad to do it with my example above, and why? And is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just extrapolate the information you need from your js object and save them in the localStorage, like:

```
var _uogradesStored = {
     upgrade1: {
          level: 1
     },
     upgrade2: {
          level: 1
     },
     upgrade3: {
          level: 1
     }
};
```

then when you retrieve the object from the storage, iterate over the "upgrade" items and get the level attribute info you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make upgrades an array and save the level as a separate item/index to chosen version.

Comment: That's how it used to be. However, ocd kicked in and I had to have everything in one object.. But that's good because I started coding this game to learn javascript as a main goal

gzp___ comment seems interesting, I will try to do what he suggested and see how it goes